# Taylor series of a complex Gaussian function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

The first few terms of Taylor series at $a=0$ of the Gaussian function $e^{-(x-a)^2}$ when $x$ is real are:

$$e^{-x^2}+a\left(2xe^{-x^2}\right)+a^2(2x^2-1)e^{-x^2}+...$$

I am wondering if one can take the "Taylor series" at $a=0$ for the complex Gaussian function $e^{-|x-a|^2}$.  Will it have the following form?

$$e^{-|x|^2}+a\left(2xe^{-|x|^2}\right)+|a|^2(2|x|^2-1)e^{-|x|^2}+...$$

I'm trying to approximate complex Gaussian around $a=0$, but am really stumbling around in the dark here, having never taken the course on complex analysis.  I read about the [relevant part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_in_complex_analysis) of the wiki article on Taylor series, but am confused.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you really mean $|x-a|^2$ instead of $(x-a)^2$ here?

Comment: Taylor series require analytic functions.  In general, absolute values lead to non-analytic functions in the complex plane.  In particular, $e^{-|x-a|^2}$ is always real, and no analytic functions are real except constants.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Hmm, I see -- thanks for clarification on analytic functions. I think instead of what I wrote I need a Taylor series of a bivariate function $e^{-(x_i-a_i)^2-(x_q-a_q)^2}$ where $x=x_i+ix_q$ and $a=a_a+ia_q$ (subscripts "i" and "q" denote in-phase and quadrature components of complex numbers).

Comment: Again, this is always real, and thus non-analytic as a function of the complex variable $a$.   On the other hand, you could regard $a_i$ and $a_q$ as separate variables, and do a multivariate Taylor expansion as a function of them.

Comment: $$ {{\rm e}^{-{x_{{i}}}^{2}-{x_{{q}}}^{2}}}+2\,{{\rm e}^{-{x_{{i}}}^{2}-{
x_{{q}}}^{2}}}x_{{i}}a_{{i}}+2\,{{\rm e}^{-{x_{{i}}}^{2}-{x_{{q}}}^{2}
}}x_{{q}}a_{{q}}+{{\rm e}^{-{x_{{i}}}^{2}-{x_{{q}}}^{2}}} \left( 2\,{x
_{{i}}}^{2}-1 \right) {a_{{i}}}^{2}+4\,{{\rm e}^{-{x_{{i}}}^{2}-{x_{{q
}}}^{2}}}x_{{i}}x_{{q}}a_{{q}}a_{{i}}+{{\rm e}^{-{x_{{i}}}^{2}-{x_{{q}
}}^{2}}} \left( 2\,{x_{{q}}}^{2}-1 \right) {a_{{q}}}^{2}
+\ldots$$